# not showing connection source code wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

Wordpress has a plugin editor that allows visitors to view my plugin's source code. I have some MySQL database connections and Azure connections that would be malicious to let others look at.

```
$connectionstring = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http|https];AccountName=[yourAccount];AccountKey=[yourKey]";
```

This is an example of what I do not what to show the visitor. Could I do this in an external PHP file, hidden away from their sights? Anyway I could accomplish this efficiently and securely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there are ways to secure these settings described in [48 Ways to Keep Your WordPress Site Secure](https://www.sitepoint.com/ways-to-keep-your-wordpress-site-secure/) which includes:

> **4. Secure wp-config.php**
>
> Lock down wp-config.php—it’s one single location that contains a wealth of critical data regarding your database, username, and password. Only you should have access.
>
> To deny access to this file, you should add the code below at the top of the .htaccess file:
>
> ```
> <files wp-config.php>
>     order allow,deny
>     deny from all
> </files>
> ```

You don't ever want to expose connection strings client-side. It's like locking your front door, then hanging the keys up on a hook on the same door.

If you can't secure this sort of stuff on wordpress, you need some sort of server-side access, which would only respond to requests from your specific wordpress domain, like a RESTful API.